# ionic 3 storage get data and show it in html

Tags: html, ionic-framework, ionic3, local-storage, storage

i want to show data in html from local storage but i got error [object promise]. i don't know how to show data in html. i can show data from console but cannot show in html. please help me

TS

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { PengaturanPage } from "../../pengaturan/pengaturan";


@IonicPage()
@Component({
selector: 'page-biodata',
templateUrl: 'biodata.html',
})
export class BiodataPage {

  inputnama: string;
  public name: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
    public navParams: NavParams, 
    private storage: Storage) {`enter code here`


  }

  saveData(){
    this.storage.set('name', this.inputnama);
  }

  loadData(){
    this.storage.get('name').then((name) => {
    console.log(name);
  });
}
```

HTML :

```html
<ion-row padding-top>
            <ion-col class="col-tengah" col-10 no-padding>
                <ion-item style="background: transparent" >
                    <ion-input class="input-biodata" [(ngModel)]="inputnama" placeholder="Nama">{{name}}</ion-input>
                </ion-item>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `saveData()` and `loadData()` somewhere of course. I assume, you did this already.

To display the data in your template, you need to store the data in any attribute of your class. In your case you want to store it like this:

```
this.storage.get('name').then((name) => {
    this.name = name;
});
```

After this `Promise` (Note: It is asynchronous, that is important to know), your `name` attribute is populated with any value your stored in LocalStorage before.
You maybe want to use `.catch()` on the `Promise` to catch any errors, that occur, when you have not stored any value for `name`.